# Can I request a route direction without rendering?

Tags: bing-maps

I will build my own style for the directions of a route, but only when I use the `setRenderOptions` Method with the `itineraryContainer` property I can access the `DirectionSteps` with a callback function (`afterStepRender` Event).

```
var directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);

// ...

directionsManager.setRenderOptions({ itineraryContainer: document.getElementById('itineraryDiv') });
```

Is there a possibility to get the Object with all DirectionSteps **without** rendering the steps in a hidden html element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a url template from Bing Maps, see in documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wayPoint.1=wayPoint1&viaWaypoint.2=viaWaypoint2&waypoint.3=wayPoint3&wayPoint.n=wayPointn&heading=heading&optimize=optimize&avoid=avoidOptions&distanceBeforeFirstTurn=distanceBeforeFirstTurn&maxSolutions=maxSolutions&routePathOutput=routePathOutput&tolerances=tolerance1,tolerance2,tolerancen&distanceUnit=distanceUnit&key=BingMapsKey
```